# "I do love you" or "I really love you" - what is the difference?

Tags: difference, emphasis

> I **do** love you.

and

> I **really** love you.

What is the difference between them?

In emphatic sentences ,we use "do"or "does"in present indefinite tense.
So, why we say,  I really love you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such context, *'do'* is used to support the counter statement.

For example -

> I ***do*** love fish, but I ***don't*** have aquarium at home.

Said that, if you want to use this with 'love', you may say...

> I ***do*** love you, but your behavior bothers me.

*really* emphasizes the statement. And thus, both the sentences *don't exactly* mean the same.

---

Note that as Ramit says in the answer, *do* can be used in response to the question `Do you love me?` ~ `Yes, I do` OR `Do you really love me?` ~ `Yes, I really do.`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,
'I do love you' should be a reply to a question.

q. Do you love me ? OR I wonder if you really love me or not ?
a. I do love you.
Here, using **do** makes sense.

'I really love you' has to be a follow-up sentence.
'really' doesn't fit.
example. I love you, I really do.

'loving you' is like 'eating apples'
The correct way of telling would be :
I eat apples ('everyday' or 'once a week').
I love you.
I think about you (every single day).

'do' or 'really' should not be used unless it's the answer to a question or a part of a bigger conversation.

example.
I do love you, but I'd rather watch TV than accompany you to your friend's wedding.

I can't say much about grammar here but this is how the sentences are used.